# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to calculate the average of the column of nested morph relation.

**Model Function**

```php
public function trader_ratings()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TraderRatings::class, 'rateable')
        ->select('rateable_id', 'rateable_type', 'rating')
        ->avg('rating');
}
```

**Controller with lazy loading**

```php
$user = auth('api')->user();
$user_id = $user->id;
$customer_classes = CustomerClassBooking::with([
    'trader_class',
    'trader_class.trader_ratings',
    'vendor',
])
    ->where('customer_id', $user_id)
    ->where('status', 'Accepted-paid')
    ->get();
```

It is not calculating the `avg` but giving the error.

Comment: Presented function is wrong. You need to show `addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: @AksenP it is the error which I am showing you when I hit the api in postman

Comment: No matter, you've presented the wrong trouble-place function.

Comment: What should I do

Comment: Find `addEagerConstraints()` and inspect which argument comes in. You've passed a value as an argument here with wrong datatype .

Comment: I haven't used `addEagerConstraints()` used in my code

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more of the error you're getting? Maybe the first 20~30 lines of the error would do, there's probably something else that could point out to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `with()` need to get the relationship. [addEagerConstraints](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOneOrMany.php#L63) is from source code. When you use eager loading, Your relationship builder will call `addEagerConstraints`.

However, your relationship method is return the string(the result of `avg()`) instead of morph relationship. So the error occurs.

You can change your method like:

```php
public function trader_ratings()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TraderRatings::class, 'rateable')->select('*', DB::raw('AVG(rating) AS avg_rating'));
}
```

Comment: The error is gone but it is giving nothing in the response `trader_ratings": []`

Comment: @ZainFarooq what is the foreign_key ?

Comment: There isn't any foreign key defined as it is morph table but the assumed foreign key is `rateable_id `

Comment: @ZainFarooq because `with` need the related key to add relationship collection to the CustomerClassBooking, or you can try to use `select *`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Your logic makes sense but still giving empty result `"trader_ratings": []`

Comment: @ZainFarooq all return empty, or just some records?

Comment: It gives some records but not every which it should return

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that trader_ratings have already calculated the avg and is no longer instance of builder that you would need for eager loading. so may be do some thing as below, (not tested the code, just from top of my head)

```
public function trader_ratings()
{
  return $this->morphMany(TraderRatings::class, 'rateable')->select('rateable_id','rateable_type','rating');
 }


// Then

$customer_classes = CustomerClassBooking::with([
         'trader_class',
         'trader_class.trader_ratings' => function($query`){
            $query->avg('rating)
         },

        ,'vendor'])-> // rest of query
```